# JFrog artifactory feed using the API

Tags: artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli

My requirement is to just see what packages/artifacts are available in a given feed

Answer (score 0):

If you're good with using a command line API to get the list of Artifacts, [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) includes a nice and flexible [search command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles), which returns the search results in a JSON format. Here's the command syntax:

```
jfrog rt s repository/and/path/in/artifactory/
```

Behind the scenes, JFrog CLI uses [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) to query the files, so you also have the option of invoking the same AQL using any REST client, such as curl. To see the actual AQL JFrog CLI uses, you can set the **JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL** environment variable to **DEBUG** and see log prints in the console when running the search command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get or list using like this

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN' -H \"Content-Type: application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.LocalRepositoryConfiguration+json\" -X GET --data http://{HostName}/artifactory/api/repositories/yourreponame
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer , I'm not familiar with this syntax .. Can I execute this on PostMan or any REST client ?

Comment: @codeztech yes you can execute on postman or even on normal powershell or git bash CLI

Comment: oh ok strangely I get a 404 when I execute the following on postman http://{HostName}/artifactory/api/repositories 
Any idea on that ? :)

Comment: @codeztech make sure you point out to your repository path correctly. I have updated my ans do it like this